# What does the term "bundled-theme" mean?

Tags: themes

I have occasionally heard the term "bundled-theme". I know what a WordPress theme is, but I don't know what a "bundled-theme" is. I came across that term recently when reviewing the WordPress documentation:

> "...For core (and bundled themes), this is always WordPress."(http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/)

Comment: This is just a term used for the default twenty-something themes shipped with wordpress.

Comment: @PieterGoosen That's worth posting as an answer... since it's the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term bundled theme is simply just a name/term used for the default (twenty-something) themes shipped with wordpress.

The current version of wordpress 3.9.1 have three of themes shipped by default, namely '[twentytwelve](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwelve)', '[twentythirteen](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen)' and '[twentyfourteen](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen)'. The two previous twenty-something themes namely '[twentyten](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyten)' and '[twentyeleven](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyeleven)' are also available for download and is still currently been supported by the wordpress team