# Use code from bundled themes in my theme and resell it

Tags: theme-twenty-thirteen

Since a while I have started comparing frameworks for wordpress in order to understand the way wordpress works.

Now that I understand the code more clearly, I have compared it to the twentythirteen and twentyfourteen themes bundled with wordpress.

I came to understand that quite alot of the code seems to be the same, apart from the functions they all seem to use and call for.

Can I do the same thing, using code from those themes?

*I'm sorry if this question has already been asked before, just didnt see it anywhere on this site...*

Any suggestions to this issue?

Comment: [Wordpress is under GPLv2 license](http://wordpress.org/about/license/). So yes, you can use the code, resell it or whatever you want. Just remember to release your product under a license compatible with GPL.

Comment: Can you change this to an answer?:P

Comment: @cybmeta not accurate, you can't change it to "compatible" if you reuse actual GPL code, it _must_ be GPL as well.

Comment: So what would this mean for me re-using code? Would i still be unable to re-sell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Themes bundled with WordPress are licensed under "GPLv2 or any later version" in full (both code and assets).

You can reuse and resell that code, as long as you abide by the GPL license, effectively meaning — resulting product's code (and assets if you use them) must be under either of:

- GPLv2 or later
- GPLv2 strict
- GPLv3

with all the implications of.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add to @Rarst answer.

> I came to understand that quite a lot of the code seems to be the same

Yes, the [**bundled themes**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143937/31545) are written by the [**Wordpress team**](http://wordpress.org/), so you would expect the coding styles between the bundled themes to be the same.

> Can I do the same thing, using code from those themes?

This was handled by @Rarst, but I would like to add to this. The bundled themes are showcases of new functionalities within Wordpress. These themes are used to target these new functionalities and the correct uses there of

Furthermore, these themes suggest the correct way how a theme should be written according to [**coding standards**](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards), although this is not the alpha and omega to coding standards as such.

These bundled themes offer a perfect base for theme developers to create their own themes on, and I believe that is why they should be used for. I've personally combined the twentytwelve and twentyfourteen themes as a base for my previous theme I developed. But you have to keep @Rarst answer in consideration here.

This is just a little useless info, but I always like to add some form of credit to these themes, something in the lines of

> This theme is based and written using the twentyfourteen theme as a base........

in my stylesheet under `Description`

Comment: I meant to say that some frameworks seem to do the same thing.

They seem to edit everything out thats not perfect and leave the rest in it.