# Structure and Display Content from Multiple Pages on Single Page

Tags: loop, pages

I am trying to display the content from multiple pages on a single page.  However, for each page I need the title, excerpt, content and featured image.  The display of each page's content has a different structure, therefore I need control over the HTML elements and their classes and ID. I also need to be able to control the order.

I've read what seems like 20 forum posts and blog articles, but none of the solutions enable control of the HTML structure for each specific set of page content, nor the order in which they are shown.

If anyone can assist, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a vast question to answer, so I'm not going to go into depth, I'm just going to cover the essential points.

You'll need to create a custom query to get all the data from your pages. Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create your custom query. Here is a basic query from the codex to get your pages

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1&post_type=page' );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        // YOUR LOOP ELEMENTS HERE

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

To display the title and post thumbnail, check the following links

- [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)
- [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)
- [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)
- [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

You should work through one of the [bundled themes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143937/31545) to see how the loop is structured and how their HTML structure looks like

To order your pages, you should have a look at the `orderby` and `order` parameters in `WP_Query` that you can use to sort your pages by in your custom query

As for control over your HTML structure, you can use the page ID's in your classes and ID's and target and style them accordingly. Make use of [`the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) to get the page ID inside the loop. Do something like this

```
<div id="whatever-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

or

```
<div class="whatever-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

**EDIT**

If you are going to need that strict control over your HTML, then you are going to need to hard code page ID's and HTML structure for each page. You can make use of conditional tags like `is_page()` for example

```
if( is_page( 'whatever' ) ) {

   //HTML Structure for page whatever

}elseif( is_page( 'whatever-1' ) ) {

   ////HTML Structure for page whatever-1
} //etc
```

Comment: thanks for this. Unfortunately, this doesn't actually allow me to create a different HTML structure for each incoming page.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Glad it helped. Enjoy :-)